# React Hooks : how to update props initialized by useEffect in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React Hooks and I'm facing this problem :

- App component initializes a map from localStorage with useEffect
- it passes this map to child component Hello

Then :

- child component copy this map in its own state and use it manage values editions.

Problem is, as you can see in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wdv5nc) console log :

```
parent map: undefined --- child map: undefined // map is first pass empty to the child component
parent map: world --- child map: undefined     // then it's populated by parent component effect but child state is not updated
```

How can I manage proper initialization of map values in child component? Do not hesitate to challenge the whole thing, I'm not sure to use effects properly here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have a `useEffect` in your child component to copy over the changing prop that parent sends down since you are initializing your local state from that prop.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default ({ initialMap }) => { 

  const [map, setMap] = useState(new Map(initialMap));
  console.log(`parent map: ${initialMap.get('name')} --- child map: ${map.get('name')}`);

  // this is what you need
  useEffect(() => {
    setMap(new Map(initialMap))
  }, [initialMap])

  const onChange = (value) => {
    setMap(prevMap => {
      prevMap.set('name', value);
      return prevMap;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Input initial value should be 'world':</label>  
      <input value={map.get('name')} 
        onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  ); 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Copying state like that is an antipattern because it creates two, unnecessary, sources of truth. It's better to pass value, along with `onChange` handler to children. This way you have one source of truth, but you can access, and control value from children component.

I have example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hpxvcf

Also, you have to create `new Map()` when changing state, so React know to rerender components.

Comment: I agree with this for most of the case but here I need to copy original values to let user save globally his modifications or cancel them. It doesn't appear in the stackblitz I provided though. Thanks for your advice